# Any() method is not working when we connect to MySql

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

Calling  Any() method on a table to check for existence of records throws an exception when we connect to MySql but it is working fine  when we connect to SqlServer
I am using the following code:

```
public IActionResult GetCustomers()
{
   DbContext db = new DbContext();
   if(db.Customers.Any())//here throws an exception when connect to mysql db
   {
     //my code
   }
   return view();
}
```

My Exception was:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code: 'No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Int16' and 'System.Boolean'.'
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetUserDefinedCoercionOrThrow(ExpressionType coercionType, Expression expression, Type convertToType)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(Expression expression, Type type, MethodInfo method)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(Expression expression, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.CreateGetValueExpression(Expression dataReaderExpression, Int32 index, TypeMaterializationInfo materializationInfo, Boolean detailedErrorsEnabled, Boolean box)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<CreateArrayInitializer>b__0(TypeMaterializationInfo mi, Int32 i)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectIterator>d__154`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.CollectionExtensions.ToReadOnly[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.NewArrayInit(Type type, IEnumerable`1 initializers)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.CreateArrayInitializer(CacheKey cacheKey, Boolean detailedErrorsEnabled)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.<Create>b__11_0(CacheKey k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.Create(IReadOnlyList`1 types)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.DefaultQuerySqlGenerator.CreateValueBufferFactory(IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory relationalValueBufferFactoryFactory, DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.<NotifyReaderCreated>b__14_0(FactoryAndReader s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.NonCapturingLazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[TParam,TValue](TValue& target, TParam param, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.NotifyReaderCreated(DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.GetResult[TResult](IEnumerable`1 valueBuffers, Boolean throwOnNullResult)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ResultEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass15_1`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at SampleEfCoreLatest.Controllers.HomeController.GetCustomers() in D:\SampleEfCoreLatest\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 49
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Do you also get the exception for: `bool b = dbContext.Customers.Any();` And what if you try: `bool b = dbContext.Customers.Take(1).Count() != 0`, which in fact is what `Any()` does

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  dbContext.Customers.Any(i=>i.CustomerId > 0); is also throwing same exception. for that, we may use bool b = dbContext.Customers.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.CustomerId > 0) != null; but my question is why Any() is not working with mysql.

Comment: Got the solution we have to use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql package instead of MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore package